# Train Keras LSTM model with a variable number of features

Tags: keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, autoencoder

I am training a seq-to-seq autoencoder in Keras and my input is `(num_examples, time_step, num_features)`. The problem is, the `num_features` is not the same for all examples and, furthermore, I will get additional examples in the future, of unknown `num_feature` size.

My code so far is:

```
    # model architecture
    inputs = Input(shape=data.shape[1:])

    encoded1 = LSTM(32, return_sequences=True)(inputs)
    encoded2 = LSTM(32)(encoded1)

    latent_space = Dense(encoding_size)(encoded2)

    decoded1 = RepeatVector(1)(latent_space)
    decoded2 = LSTM(encoding_size, return_sequences=True)(decoded1)

    sequence_autoencoder = Model(inputs, decoded2)
```

I tried with: `inputs = Input(shape=(1, None))` but it throws an error. Any ideas on how I could approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In using lstm the variying size of input can be handled by setting None to timestep in input shape.

```
inputs = Input(shape=(BATCH_SIZE,None,channels))
```

This way you can feed variable size inputs to the LSTM.

Comment: I dont fully undestand this solution .. does this only work with categorization problems? What about time series, where timestep is explicit?

Comment: @robertotomás The solution could work for time series prediction too. The idea is to feed a variable size sequence for inference.

Comment: It seems like a variable `steps`, not `features`.